# Query using data from wrong column

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

The title may be a bit misleading as I didn't know exactly how to phrase it. I have a PHP page which shows a listing of records with search filters. The code is given below. The page gets displayed correctly but in one of the columns I get following database error for MS SQL

```
Error Number: 22018

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Marie Stopes International' to data type int.

SELECT * FROM ctbl_mas_funder WHERE flag = 0 AND id = 'Marie Stopes International'

Filename: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FMS\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

I think its because instead of pulling an ID for query it is pulling the data from some other column, but cannot quite put my finger on what is causing this.

The code for the page is as below.

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/plugins/forms/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/plugins/forms/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/plugins/forms/select2/select2.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/plugins/tables/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/plugins/tables/datatables/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/app.js"></script><!-- Core js functions -->

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/pages/data-tables.js"></script><!-- Init plugins only for page -->



<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="crumb">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="icon16 i-home-4"></i>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Manage Funding</a></li>
      <li class="active">
        <?=$title ?>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="heading" class="page-header">
      <h1><i class="icon20 i-table-2"></i>
        <?=$title ?>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="icon"><i class="icon20 i-table"></i></div>
            <h4>
              <?=$title ?>
            </h4>
            <a href="#" class="minimize"></a>
            <div class="flexigrid" style="width: 100%;">
              <div class="tDiv">
                <div class="tDiv2">
                  <?php 
                  $f_manange_funding=explode(',', $this->session->userdata('f_manange_funding'));

if (in_array('6', $m_projects) or $this->session->userdata('user_type')=='admin') 
{?>
                  <!--<div class="fbutton tip" title="Download Word" onclick="javascript:document.location.href='<?php echo site_url("office").'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$this->uri->segment(3); ?>/download_word'"><div><span class="word" style="padding-left: 20px;">Word</span></div></div>
                    <div class="btnseparator"></div>-->
                  <?php }
if (in_array('5', $m_projects) or $this->session->userdata('user_type')=='admin') 
{?>
                  <!--<div class="fbutton tip" title="Download Excel" onclick="javascript:document.location.href='<?php echo site_url("office").'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$this->uri->segment(3); ?>/download_excel'"><div><span class="excel" style="padding-left: 20px;">Excel</span></div></div> <div class="btnseparator"></div> -->
                  <?php }
if (in_array('7', $m_projects) or $this->session->userdata('user_type')=='admin') 
{?>
                  <!--<div class="fbutton tip" title="Download Pdf" onclick="javascript:document.location.href='<?php echo site_url("office").'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$this->uri->segment(3); ?>/download_pdf'"><div><span class="pdf" style="padding-left: 20px;">Pdf</span></div></div>
                        <div class="btnseparator"></div>-->
                  <?php } 
if (in_array('8', $m_projects) or $this->session->userdata('user_type')=='admin') 
{?>
                  <!--<div class="fbutton tip" title="Print" onclick="javascript:window.open('<?php echo site_url("office").'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$this->uri->segment(3); ?>/print_page', 'mywindow', 'location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,  width=600,height=600')"><div><span class="print" style="padding-left: 20px;">Print</span></div></div>
                        <div class="btnseparator"></div>-->
                  <?php } ?>
                  <div class="fbutton tip" title="Help"   >
                    <div><span class="help_ic" style="padding-left: 20px;"><a href="#myModal"   data-toggle="modal">Help</a></span></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End .panel-heading -->
          <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
      //flash messages

        if($this->session->flashdata('feedback'))
        {
          echo '<div class="alert alert-success">';
            echo '<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>';
            echo $this->session->flashdata('feedback');
          echo '</div>';       
        } ?>

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  id="dataTable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th > Funding Hierarchy</th>
                  <th >Project Code </th>
                  <th >Country of implementation</th>
                  <th >Source of funding </th>
                  <th > Primary Donor</th>
                  <th > Contracting donor</th>
                  <th > Contracting recipient </th>
                  <th >Short  Title</th>
                  <th >Funding status</th>
                  <th width="8%">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php
               $str="";

    if(($funding_mechanism !="")  or ($primary_donor !="")    or ($contracting_donor_funder_code !="" ) or ($funder_code_primary !="" )     or ($funding_manager !="" ) ){




               if($fundingstatus !="")
               {



                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.fundingstatus ='$fundingstatus'";
               }

                 if($project_code !="")
               {

                    if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.project_code='$project_code'";
               }




                if($fundingHierarchy !="")
               {
                    if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.fundingHierarchy='$fundingHierarchy'";
               }



                if($funding_mechanism !="")
               {
                    if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_fin.funding_mechanism='$funding_mechanism'";
               }



                if($subfunding_title !="")
               {

                   if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.subfunding_title='$subfunding_title'";
               }




                if($primary_donor !="")
               {

                   if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.primary_donor='$primary_donor'";
               }

                 if($source_funding !="")
               {

                   if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                // $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.source_funding='$source_funding'";

                    $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.source_funding  REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:\"$source_funding\".*'";
               }




                 if($contracting_donor !="")
               {
                    if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.contracting_donor='$contracting_donor'";
               }



                if($contracting_recipient !="")
               {
                    if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.contracting_recipient='$contracting_recipient'";
               }

                if($funder_code_source !="")
               {
                    if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.funder_code_source='$funder_code_source'";
               }


               if($contracting_donor_funder_code !="")
               {
                    if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.contracting_donor_funder_code='$contracting_donor_funder_code'";
               }



                 if($funder_code_primary !="")
               {
                    if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.funder_code_primary='$funder_code_primary'";
               }  






               if($country_implemention !="")
               {
                    if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                // $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.country_implemention='$country_implemention'";

                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_info.country_implemention  REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:\"$country_implemention\".*'";
               }


                if($funding_manager !="")
               {
                    if($str!="")
                   {
                      $str=$str." and ";  
                   }
                 $str=$str."ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt.funding_manager='$funding_manager'";
               }





            $query_search = $this->db->query('SELECT ctbl_contract_funding_info.* ,ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt.funding_manager,ctbl_contract_workflow.id as id1,ctbl_contract_workflow.family_id as main_id ,ctbl_contract_workflow.parent_type 
FROM ctbl_contract_workflow
LEFT JOIN ctbl_contract_funding_info ON ctbl_contract_funding_info.contract_id = ctbl_contract_workflow.id 
LEFT JOIN ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt ON ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt.contract_id = ctbl_contract_funding_info.contract_id

LEFT JOIN ctbl_contract_funding_fin ON ctbl_contract_funding_fin.contract_id = ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt.contract_id
WHERE   '.$str.' 
ORDER BY ctbl_contract_workflow.id asc');
            $total=$query_search->num_rows() ;
            foreach($query_search->result_array() as $row_search)
            {



                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row_search['fundingHierarchy'].'</td>';

                if($row_search['project_code']!='')
                {
                echo '<td>E'.$row_search['project_code'].'</td>';
                }
                else
                {
                echo '<td></td>';   
                }

                if($row_search['country_implemention']=='')
                {


            $data['list1'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$country_implemention,'ctbl_mas_country');




                echo '<td>'.$data['list1'][0]['name'].'</td>';

                }
                else
                {
                    ?>
              <td><?php $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ctbl_mas_country order by rank desc');
    $total=$query->num_rows() ;
    if($total>0)
    {
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {

        if(unserialize($row_search['country_implemention'])!='')
                {
                $implementing_agency= unserialize($row_search['country_implemention']);
                }
                else
                {
                $implementing_agency=array();
                }



                if (in_array($row['id'], $implementing_agency))
                {
                 echo $row['name']."<br>";  
                }
    }
    }
    ?></td>
                <?php 



                }


                if($source_funding!='' || $source_funding!='Array')
                {


            $data['list'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$source_funding,'ctbl_mas_funder');

                echo '<td>'.$data['list'][0]['name'].'</td>';




                }

                else
                {


                    ?>
                <td><?php
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ctbl_mas_funder Where flag=0 ');
    $total=$query->num_rows() ;
    if($total>0)
    {
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {

        if(unserialize($row_search['source_funding'])!='')
                {
                $source_funding= unserialize($row_search['source_funding']);
                }
                else
                {
                $source_funding=array();
                }



                if (in_array($row['id']."-".$row['code'], $source_funding))
                {
                 echo $row['name']."<br>";
                }




    }
    }
    ?></td>
                <?php 

                }

                $data['list1'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',substr($row_search['primary_donor'],0, strpos($row_search['primary_donor'], "-")),'ctbl_mas_funder');
                echo '<td>'.$data['list1'][0]['name'].'</td>';
                ?>
                <td><?php 

                                                $c=explode("-",$row_search['contracting_donor']);

                                                if(is_array($c) && $c[1]!='')
                                                {


                                                $data['list2'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$c[0],'ctbl_mas_funder');
                                                    echo $data['list2'][0]['name'];

                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    echo  $row_search['contracting_donor'];
                                                }

                                                 ?></td>
                <td><?php  




  if($row_search['contracting_recipient']!='Select')
                                                  {
                                                      if($row_search['type_recipient']!='Select')
                                                  {
    if($row_search['type_recipient']=='MSI partnership')
    {

    if($row_search['contracting_recipient']!='Select')
    {
         $data['list_cd'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$row_search['contracting_recipient'],'ctbl_mas_msi_entities');
         $d=$data['list_cd'][0]['name'] ;
    }
    else
    {
        $d='';
    }
        ?>
                  <?php echo $d ; ?>
                  <?php     
    }
    else if($row_search['type_recipient']=='External partner')
    {

    if($row_search['contracting_recipient']!='Select')
    {
         $data['list_cd'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$row_search['contracting_recipient'],'ctbl_mas_external_partners');
         $d=$data['list_cd'][0]['name'] ;
    }
    else
    {
        $d='';
    }
        ?>
                  <?php echo $d ; ?>
                  <?php     
    }
    else if($row_search['type_recipient']=='MSI funding stream')
    {

    if($row_search['contracting_recipient']!='Select')
    {
         $data['list_cd'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$row_search['contracting_recipient'],'ctbl_mas_msi_funding_streams');
         $d=$data['list_cd'][0]['name'] ;
    }
    else
    {
        $d='';
    }
        ?>
                  <?php echo $d ; ?>
                  <?php     
    }
    else if($row_search['type_recipient']=='MSI funding stream - project donor')
    {

    if($row_search['contracting_recipient']!='Select')
    {
         $data['list_cd'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$row_search['contracting_recipient'],'ctbl_mas_funder');
         $d=$data['list_cd'][0]['name'] ;
    }
    else
    {
        $d='';
    }
        ?>
                  <?php echo $d ; ?>
                  <?php     
    }


                                                  }}?></td>
                <?php 
                echo '<td>'.$row_search['subfunding_title'].'</td>';

                echo '<td>'.$row_search['fundingstatus'].'</td>';
                echo '<td class="crud-actions">';
                 if($row_search['main_id']==$row_search['id1'])
                 {
                echo '<a href="'.site_url("office").'/master/create_entry/view/?contract_id='.$this->encryption->encode($row_search['id1']).'" class="tip"   title="View Details"><i class="icon16  i-zoom-in"></i>  </a>';
                 }
                 else
                 {
                echo '<a href="'.site_url("office").'/master/create_entry/view_sub_funding/?contract_id='.$this->encryption->encode($row_search['id1']).'&main_id='.$this->encryption->encode($row_search['main_id']).'" class="tip"   title="View Details"><i class="icon16  i-zoom-in"></i>  </a>';

                 }

                //echo '<a href="'.site_url("office").'/master/create_entry/update/?contract_id='.$this->encryption->encode($row_search['id']).'" class="tip" title="Edit"><i class="icon16 i-pencil"></i> </a>';  

                //echo '<a  class="tip" title="Delete" href="'.site_url("office").'/master/create_entry/delete/?contract_id='.$this->encryption->encode($row_search['id']).'"  title="Remove"><i class="icon16 i-remove"></i></a>';                   
                echo ' </td></tr>';
               }
            /// to show no records

            /// to show no records

             }else{
//// searching results query ends here  
//// searching results query echo ends here        



              $query_search = $this->db->query('SELECT ctbl_contract_funding_info.* ,ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt.funding_manager,ctbl_contract_workflow.id as id1,ctbl_contract_workflow.family_id as main_id,ctbl_contract_workflow.parent_type 
FROM ctbl_contract_workflow
LEFT JOIN ctbl_contract_funding_info ON ctbl_contract_funding_info.contract_id = ctbl_contract_workflow.id 
LEFT JOIN ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt ON ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt.contract_id = ctbl_contract_workflow.id

LEFT JOIN ctbl_contract_funding_fin ON ctbl_contract_funding_fin.contract_id = ctbl_contract_funding_mgmt.contract_id

ORDER BY ctbl_contract_workflow.id asc');
            $total=$query_search->num_rows() ;
            foreach($query_search->result_array() as $row_search)
              {


                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row_search['fundingHierarchy'].'</td>';
                if($row_search['project_code']!='')
                {
                echo '<td>E'.$row_search['project_code'].'</td>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<td>'.$row_search['project_code'].'</td>';
                }
                ?>
                <td><?php $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ctbl_mas_country order by rank desc');
    $total=$query->num_rows() ;
    if($total>0)
    {
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {

        if(unserialize($row_search['country_implemention'])!='')
                {
                $implementing_agency= unserialize($row_search['country_implemention']);
                }
                else
                {
                $implementing_agency=array();
                }



                if (in_array($row['id'], $implementing_agency))
                {
                 echo $row['name']."<br>";  
                }
    }
    }
    ?></td>
                <td><?php
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ctbl_mas_funder Where flag=0 ');
    $total=$query->num_rows() ;
    if($total>0)
    {
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {

        if(unserialize($row_search['source_funding'])!='')
                {
                $source_funding= unserialize($row_search['source_funding']);
                }
                else
                {
                $source_funding=array();
                }

                if (in_array($row['id']."-".$row['code'], $source_funding))
                {
                 echo $row['name']."<br>";
                }




    }
    }
    ?></td>
                <?php 
                $data['list1'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',substr($row_search['primary_donor'],0, strpos($row_search['primary_donor'], "-")),'ctbl_mas_funder');
                echo '<td>'.$data['list1'][0]['name'].'</td>';
                    ?>
                <td>
                                                <?php 
                                                //echo  $row['contracting_donor'];
                                                $code_id =explode("-",$row_search['contracting_donor']);



                                                if(trim($row_search['fundingHierarchy']) == 'Donor Funding'){

                                                $data['donor_name'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$code_id[0],'ctbl_mas_funder');
                                                echo $data['donor_name'][0]['name'];

                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    echo  $row_search['contracting_donor'];
                                                }
                                                 ?>

                                                 </td>

                <td> 
                            <?php                                                  
                            if($row_search['contracting_recipient']!='Select')
                            {
                            if($row_search['type_recipient']!='Select')
                            {                                                       


                            if($row_search['type_recipient']=='MSI partnership')
                            {

                            if($row_search['contracting_recipient']!='Select')
                            {
                            $data['list_cd'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$row_search['contracting_recipient'],'ctbl_mas_partnership');
                            $d=$data['list_cd'][0]['name'] ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            $d='';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <?php echo $d ; ?>
                            <?php   
                            }
                            else if($row_search['type_recipient']=='External partner')
                            {

                            if($row_search['contracting_recipient']!='Select')
                            {
                            $data['list_cd'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$row_search['contracting_recipient'],'ctbl_mas_external_partners');
                            $d=$data['list_cd'][0]['name'] ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            $d='';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <?php echo $d ; ?>
                            <?php   
                            }
                            else if($row_search['type_recipient']=='MSI funding stream')
                            {

                            if($row_search['contracting_recipient']!='Select')
                            {
                            $data['list_cd'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$row_search['contracting_recipient'],'ctbl_mas_msi_funding_streams');
                            $d=$data['list_cd'][0]['name'] ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            $d='';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <?php echo $d ; ?>
                            <?php   
                            }
                            else if($row_search['type_recipient']=='MSI funding stream - project donor')
                            {

                            if($row_search['contracting_recipient']!='Select')
                            {
                            $data['list_cd'] = $this->common_model->get_by_id('id',$row_search['contracting_recipient'],'ctbl_mas_funder');
                            $d=$data['list_cd'][0]['name'] ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            $d='';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <?php echo $d ; ?>
                            <?php   
                            }


                            }
                            }

                            ?>                                                   
                    </td>


                <?php 
                echo '<td>'.$row_search['subfunding_title'].'</td>';

                echo '<td>'.$row_search['fundingstatus'].'</td>';
                echo '<td class="crud-actions">';
                  if($row_search['main_id']==$row_search['id1'])
                 {
                echo '<a href="'.site_url("office").'/master/create_entry/view/?contract_id='.$this->encryption->encode($row_search['id1']).'" class="tip"   title="View Details"><i class="icon16  i-zoom-in"></i>  </a>';
                 }
                 else
                 {
                echo '<a href="'.site_url("office").'/master/create_entry/view_sub_funding/?contract_id='.$this->encryption->encode($row_search['id1']).'&main_id='.$this->encryption->encode($row_search['main_id']).'" class="tip"   title="View Details"><i class="icon16  i-zoom-in"></i>  </a>';

                 }

                //echo '<a href="'.site_url("office").'/master/create_entry/update/?contract_id='.$this->encryption->encode($row_search['id']).'" class="tip" title="Edit"><i class="icon16 i-pencil"></i> </a>';  

                //echo '<a  class="tip" title="Delete" href="'.site_url("office").'/master/create_entry/delete/?contract_id='.$this->encryption->encode($row_search['id']).'"  title="Remove"><i class="icon16 i-remove"></i></a>';

                echo ' </td></tr>';
               }

             }
              ?>
                  </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php  require_once('help.php');?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-offset-4">
                  <div class="pad-left15"> <a href="<?php echo site_url("office")."/master/funding_management"; ?>" class="btn btn-default tip" title="Cancel"   rel="widget-content"><i class="i-cancel"></i>Cancel/Back</a> </div>
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>
          <!-- End .panel-body --> 
        </div>
        <!-- End .widget --> 
      </div>
      <!-- End .col-lg-12  --> 
    </div>
    <!-- End .row-fluid  --> 

  </div>
  <!-- End .container-fluid  --> 
</div>
```

Comment: The `id` column is more-than-likely an `int` type. So when the engine runs your query it needs to evaluate the right-hand side of that clause to `int`; ergo, you cannot convert the string `'Marie Stopes International'` to an int, hence the error. You should either use an numerical ID or look in the column that has the `varchar` name.

Comment: Parry, which line do you have an error at?